# Use linq to count in many to many table

Tags: linq

I have two table with many-to-many relation ship: director(id, name), movie(id, name, year) 
and the relation ship table is dir_mov(did,mid)
I want to use and group by the number of movie a director direct using linq. 
How can i solve this?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325278/group-by-in-linq - seems similiar to your example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use join and group by. Joining director table and relationship table is enough.

```
var result = yourDbContext.director
                .Join(yourDbContext.Dir_Mov, d => d.Id, m => m.did,
                    (d, m) => new {DirectorId = d.Id, MovieId = m.mid})
.GroupBy(g => g.DirectorId)
.Select(s => new {s.Key, CountOfMovie = s.Count()}).ToList();
```

You have to change yourDbContext is your own context or repository.

Comment: Your welcome, if you accept the answer, it's looking solved.

Comment: If you have a Join followed by a GroupBy, wouldn't it be better to use a GroupJoin?

Comment: I usually prefer groupJoin for outer joins. In here, it would use. However I am not sure about performance.